# Determining convergence of $P(z)=1-\exp(i\theta)+\exp^{2}(i\theta)+\dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, power-series

Given the geometric series $$P(z)=1-\exp(i\theta)+\exp^{2}(i\theta)-\exp^{3}(i\theta)+\dots$$
where $z$ represents a complex number, I would like to determine the values of $\theta$ such that $P(z)$ converges.

From the geometric ratio $r=-\exp(i\theta)$, I determined that $\lvert r \rvert=1$. so I used the alegbraic formula for sum to infinity $S_N$ of a geometric series to obtain
$$S_N=\frac{1-(-\exp(i\theta))^N}{1-(-\exp(i\theta))},
$$ where $N\to \infty$.

Using this expression, how should I proceed to find the values of $\theta$ such that $S_N$ converges?

Edit: Most of the people that replied says that the series is divergent. 
However, according to the textbook 'Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering' by Riley, Hobson and Bence, the above series converges except at $\theta =\pi$. I've posted the screenshots [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEbEh.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03KzW.png).

Comment: What's the connection between $z$ and $\theta$?

Comment: I suppose it is more on $P(e^{i\theta})=...$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $z$ just represents a complex number, meaning that the function $P$ is a complex function.

Comment: @Taenyfan That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @Pagode you can say that but it's trivial and not that important for what I'm trying to do haha

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos ok, here $z=rexp(i\theta)$ where $r=1$ so $z=exp(i\theta)$

Comment: They (the authors of the book) are wrong. They seem to confuse the convergence of the series with regular behaviour of the represented function at points of the circle of convergence. The series is Abel-summable for $\theta \notin \pi + 2\pi\mathbb{Z}$, but that is a different concept than convergence.

Comment: Yes, what it says in the book  is simply wrong. Cf. Daniel Fischer's comment for details that I really should include.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$, $\bigl|\exp(i\theta)\bigr|=e^{\operatorname{Re}(i\theta)}=1$ and therefore your series never converges, since you don't have $\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n\exp(i\theta)^n=0$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79039/discussion-on-answer-by-jose-carlos-santos-determining-convergence-of-pz1-e).

Answer (score 0):

**First method**

So you your have geometric sum:

$$ S_N= \frac{1+(-1)^Ne^{i\theta N}}{1+e^{i\theta}} $$

So you only need

$$ \kappa_N\triangleq \Re((-1)^Ne^{i\theta N})= \cos((\theta+\pi)N) $$

convergent

Suppose it converges to $l$:

$$ (\theta+\pi)N = \arccos(l ) + o(1)$$

So necesserely:

$$ \theta = -\pi \mod[2\pi] $$

Idem for $ \Im $ Part

But your quotient isn't define so it doesn't works. Never convergent.

**Second Method**

Your general term doesn't tend to zero so divergent series it involves !

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help. However I'm still confused because a textbook claims that the series is convergent. I've added a link in my main post. Please take a look and advise me on whether it is wrong if you have time.

Comment: Have you well copied the textbook ?